# Visual state manager does not work on a button in a collection view

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to change the background color or text color of a button in a collection view when clicked, this is what I have so far, but it is not working. I even tried to have the button as the root but the state still does not change

```
<CollectionView
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Suburbs}"
                    SelectionMode="None"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSpacing="5" />
                    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout
                                VerticalOptions="Start">
                                <Button
                                    Padding="15"
                                    CornerRadius="10"
    
                                    BorderColor="Black"
                                    BorderWidth="1"
                                    TextColor="Black"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                    Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference browse}, Path=BindingContext.CitySelectedCommand}"
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                    Text="{Binding name}"
                                    HeightRequest="30"
                                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                   <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ColorStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red"/>
                                                </VisualState.Setters>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                </Button>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </StackLayout>
``
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `ListView` or `StackLayout` as a workaround? There are lots of strange side effects when using the `CollectionView` in Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: You may also need to change the name of your `VisualStateGroup` to match what Xamarin.Forms expects: `<VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">`

Answer (score 2):

Actually `VisualStateGroup`  does work .

However  the color only changes when you're `pressing` on the button , the color will change to origin color after you release the button .

Refer to [Visual states in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual-state-manager#visual-states-in-xamarinforms).

---

If you want the button stays another color after clicking on it , you need to create a property in the model and bind it to the `TextColor/BackgroundColor`.

#### Xaml

```
 TextColor="{Binding color}"
 Command="{Binding command}"
```

#### Model

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public string name { get; set; }


        public Color _color;
        public Color color { 
            get { return _color; }
            set {
                _color = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ICommand command { get; set; }


        bool isClick = false;
        public Model()
        {
            color = Color.Black;
            command = new Command((obj)=> {
                isClick = !isClick;

                color = isClick ? Color.Red : Color.Black;
            });
        }
    }
```